# google map display

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting problem in google map screen, it display blank google map screen contains tiles in whole screen map is not being generate

I have done every settings proper, as per getting solution from net for same problem still I cannot resolve problem pls anyone can help me for this ?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gmaptest5"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gmaptest5.Gmap5MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="MY API KEY"/>

  </application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>

 <permission
  android:name="com.example.gmaptest5.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmaptest5.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/> 

 </manifest>
```

**Main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapview1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:enabled="true" 
     android:clickable="true" 
  android:apiKey="MY API KEY" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Main.Java**

```
   public class Gmap5MainActivity extends MapActivity {
private MapView myMapView;
LocationManager locationManager;
private Location myLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmap5_main);

    myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
    double lat = 19.7888;
       double longi = 52.535;        

      GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat *1E6),(int) (longi *1E6));
    //GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()* 1000000), (int)  (location.getLatitude()* 1000000));
    MapController mc = myMapView.getController();

    mc.setZoom(18);
    mc.animateTo(p);
    // Enable Sattelite-Mode
    myMapView.setSatellite(true);
    myMapView.getMapCenter();
    myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    myMapView.invalidate();   
    myMapView.getOverlays();
    myMapView.getProjection();      
    this.myLocation = new Location("gps");
    this.myLocation.setLongitude(77.52436144125092);
    this.myLocation.setLatitude(13.05096452223662);
    Double lat1 = myLocation.getLatitude();
    Double longi1 = myLocation.getLongitude();
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat1.intValue(), longi1.intValue());
    mc.setCenter(point);*/
}
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
    myMapView.getController().setZoom(myMapView.getZoomLevel() + 1);

    return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
    myMapView.getController().setZoom(myMapView.getZoomLevel() - 1);
    return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
    myMapView.setSatellite(true);
    return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T) {
    myMapView.setSatellite(false);
    myMapView.setTraffic(true);
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gmap5_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
  }
```

Comment: Google Map features dont work unless you Export and Sign the application. They also dont work unless you are running it on a device.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing `Google Map API V1` with `API V2`, if you want to use `Google Map V2` as it looks by your `Manifest` file then you can check this blog post I wrote on how to add a `Google map API V2` to your application:

[Google Map API V2 Android](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

if you want to use `API V1` then you will have to change your `Manifest` file as it currently set to use `API V2`, follow this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: Thanks for help, i have tried with both of this solutions with API1 and API2 but could not found solution . can anybody give me ready example help of API1 or API2 pls ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Google MAP API V1, if you need any help with implementing API V2. then you can ask any question.

Comment: If you have ready example of API2 then pls give me for my reference or else pls suggest me reference site where i can get easy solution to get google map in my tablet device

Comment: @Dipali, I don't have a ready implementation for a map application but I have supplied you with a guide on how to achieve this. if you encounter any problem with my guide please let me know what exactly is the problem.

Comment: i have tried with those examples of API1 and API2 ,but in both i m getting proble. In API1 example i cannot run my application in tab, its giving blank tiles in google map where as in API2 example its giving problem in run, its being closed forcefully. what should i do ?

Comment: if you want me to help you... then go over my guide again, perform all steps and come back here with the new code and a new logcat output when the application is force closing.

Comment: what do you mean by: "and also sent code..."? where did you sent it?

Comment: please go thru this link where i have done all steps which you guide me and created 2 examples of API1 and API2                          [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542603/debug-error-while-running?noredirect=1#comment22025672_155426030