# Debug Error while running

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have tried with both solutions given for my previous problem which was giving me error in Google Map, the reason was I was mixing API1 and API2 code structure in my example, but after I got this reason of my problem I have again create 2 examples one for API1 and second for API2 but in any of example I had not got solution it can not run my application into tablet and gives me problem like:

```
"Application stopped unexpectedly.please try again".
```

So anybody can help me exacltly where I'm wrong, I'm going to put my whole code of API1 example and API2 example with this forum.

---

### Google Map API1 example

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemapapi1_21march"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MapMarkerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**MainLayout.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
    />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class GM1_21_MarchMainActivity extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapView; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gm1_21__march_main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gm1_21__march_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

### Google Map API2 example

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemapapi2_21march"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="com.example.googlemapapi2_21march.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.example.googlemapapi2_21march.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemapapi2_21march.GMAPI2_MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>

 <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="AIzaSyAy_I76CpPtTMq3X6P8y78OamvLf_yaHJI" />

 </manifest>
```

**MainLayout.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class GMAPI2_MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmapi2__main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gmapi2__main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what says the Logfile?

Comment: There is a loc cat written by eclipse. It gives you detailed information about the problem.

Comment: where is it located ? pls give me full path

Comment: Eclipse->Window->Show View->Android Log Cat or search for it in Eclipse->Window->Show View->Other...

Comment: i got it where its located, but how to load 'loc cat' when i run my application in android tab ?

Comment: **It gives following error**                                         03-21 16:25:02.830: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected
03-21 16:25:02.830: E/PGA(520): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
03-21 16:25:03.680: D/dalvikvm(882): GC_CONCURRENT freed 410K, 55% free 2674K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 0ms+0ms
03-21 16:25:03.830: W/PGA(520): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)                                                   **but how to check this when i run my application in TAB?**

Answer (score 0):

For the Google Maps API V2, for what I see now you are using the wrong Activity for your map layout. You are using the `SupportMapFragment` fragment, and there for you have to use the `FragmentActivity` object and not a simple `Activity`. try to change it to `FragmentActivity`.

And tell us what changed.

Comment: i have just changed in java file and changed as                       **public class GMAPI2_MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {**        still its not being run in my tab, its giving me error like "Application has stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: put you new logcat in the question

Comment: here is logcat **03-21 18:15:37.750: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected
03-21 18:15:37.750: E/PGA(520): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
03-21 18:15:37.750: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected
03-21 18:15:38.960: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected
03-21 18:15:38.960: E/PGA(520): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed**  but how it will affect when error is coming in tab, and i m running this application seperatly in tab by putting apk file

Comment: put your "Full stack trace" in the "Question", I can't understand anything this way.

Comment: length is being too long when i put full stack                           **03-21 18:15:37.750: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected 03-21 18:15:37.750: E/PGA(520):                           PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed                         03-21 18:15:37.750: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected              03-21 18:15:38.960: W/HdIpc(520): hd_ipc_send: not connected           03-21 18:15:38.960: E/PGA(520): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed**

Comment: then remove the code for Map API V1 if you decided to use API V2... and place the stack trace instead.

Comment: ok i will sent you but, i m getting problem in my TAB, how can it will identify by my stack trace ? because i m not debugging it with TAB , i just put my .apk file in TAB and run it seperately...

Comment: i think its problem of something else, because my one application run without error but its giving blank google map page, so sometimes it gives page like this.

Comment: if you are receiving a blank map with zoom options then you should  check again that you are using the right key(maybe try to generate it again). check that you turned on the right API in the console. and check that you are referencing the google-play-services library correctly. check this guide I wrote for google maps: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435

Comment: i have checked by generating 2-3 API keys, and also add reference of "Google Play Servies" in my project , still its giving problem. Your this reference of code giving error in my TAB "program closed unexpectedly" .

Comment: Should i add my ".keystore" file into project folder ? i think that is the problem ?

Comment: google map API is comptible with android SDK 4.2 ? i hope this is not an issue

Comment: no you don't need to add it to your project folder. and yes it compatible.

Comment: Then what is the problem ? why i cant succeed in google map ? i have tried with everything ? :(